# How do I calculate the load time penalty for Node.js package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

To give some context, I'm interested in learning how to optimise the cold start time of a Node.js Express application running onboard a Google Cloud Function.

So far, I've learned the biggest penalty for cold boots is the loading of dependencies using require statements. As an software engineer a scientific mind tells me it will be based on number of files, size of files, number of dependencies, caching. However, perhaps optimising is more of an art than science so any pointers or feedback from your own experience is most appreciated.

My questions are

1. If I surround a `const x = require('x')` with two `process.hrtime()` statements and measure the time difference, will I be measuring the load time for the entire package load time of 'x'?
2. If so, does this include the loading of *all* files within this package? How about the dependencies this package requires- when are they loaded (which leads to my third question 3).
3. If a require statement is inside a conditional block e.g. `if (condition) { const x = require('x'); }`, at what point is it 'loaded' and what does 'loaded' really mean (i.e. in memory, parsed, executed etc)? Will it 'load' at the moment in runtime the statement is reached (or not), or will the `require` happen regardless when the program begins execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `require` is just a normal function which either returns the module if it's in memory or loads it if it isn't, which means reading the file, parsing it and executing it (and of course it may involve requiring other dependances).

There's no problem benchmarking it (just make sure you measure the *first* require of a file, as the module is cached).

If a `require` is in your file but isn't executed (for example because it's behind an `if` statement), it won't have any more effect than if it weren't in your file. And the loading won't happen before the statement is reached.